# How to get the current value from a spinner and pass it to text View of another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, textview, spinner

I want to retrieve a value from the spinner and pass it to the textView of another class and I am not figuring out the way how to do this any help would be appreciated? I am a new to Android :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please add your code to the question.

Comment: Yes I tried but it only gave the first value of spinner that was set by default

Comment: Add your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply this is how you get selected value from a spinner:

```
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

There are many ways to pass it to another activity, here are some of them:

- Pass it through an intent as extras
- Save it as a Singleton
- Save it in the shared preferences
- Make it some kind of a static variable in a static class

Here is an example using the first way. Suppose you will click a button after selecting a value from a spinner and want to pass the value to the next activity

```
String text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
            intent.putExtra("mySpinnerValue", text);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And inside the onCreate method of MainActivity2, do the following:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String text = bundle.getString("mySpinnerValue");

    myTextView.setText(text);
```